# Inserting data into db is not working with Spring Data JPA + Eclipselink + JTA

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, spring-data, jta

I'm trying to configure multiple datasources with spring data jpa + eclipselink, seems like using jta is my only choice, after lots of research on this topic, I got below output, that said I am trying to insert two entity into two tables from different db -- department table and employee table. Query is fine but insertion operations are not working without errors thrown.

Pls take a look at my code

app-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <!--<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="test" id="dataSource" resource-ref="true"/>-->

    <bean abstract="true" id="baseDS" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection" value="true" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource1" parent="baseDS">
        <property name="url">
            <value>${jdbc1.url}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource2" parent="baseDS">
        <property name="url">
            <value>${jdbc2.url}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="baseJTADS" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" abstract="true" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="poolSize" value="3" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jtaDs1" parent="baseJTADS">
        <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="XA1DBMS" />
        <property name="xaDataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jtaDs2" parent="baseJTADS">
        <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="XA2DBMS" />
        <property name="xaDataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
    </bean>



    <bean abstract="true" id="baseEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.fxbird.springjpa.model"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="databasePlatform">org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform</prop>
                <prop key="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements">true</prop>
                <prop key="eclipselink.weaving">false</prop>
                <prop key="eclipselink.logging.level">fine</prop>
                <prop key="eclipselink.allow-zero-id">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emfCompany" parent="baseEmf">
        <!--<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="company" />-->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="jtaDs1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emfEmp" parent="baseEmf">
        <!--<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="employee" />-->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="jtaDs2"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
        <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" init-method="init"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="forceShutdown" value="true"/>
        <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager"/>
        <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction"/>
        <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.fxbird.springjpa.service"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.fxbird.springjpa.repo.company"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="emfCompany" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager">
    </jpa:repositories>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.fxbird.springjpa.repo.emp"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="emfEmp" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager">
    </jpa:repositories>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

    <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```

DeptRepo:

```
@Repository()
public interface DeptRepo extends JpaRepository<Department,Integer> {

}
```

EmployeeRepo:

```
public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class DepartmentService {
    @Autowired
    DeptRepo deptRepo;
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepo employeeRepo;

    @Transactional
    public void addDepartment(Department department){
        deptRepo.save(department);
    }

    public List<Department> findAllDepartments(){
        return deptRepo.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee){
        employeeRepo.save(employee);
    }
}
```

test class:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext context=new GenericXmlApplicationContext("/app-context.xml");

        DepartmentService departmentService=(DepartmentService)context.getBean("departmentService");

        Department department=new Department();
        department.setCreateDate(new Date());
        department.setDeptName("HR");

        departmentService.addDepartment(department); //not working at all!!!

        List<Department> allDepartments = departmentService.findAllDepartments();
        System.out.println(allDepartments.size());

        Employee employee=new Employee();
        employee.setEmpName("Kurt");
        employee.setDeptNo(department.getDeptNo());
        departmentService.addEmployee(employee); //not working at all!!!
    }
}
```

there are two db -- company and employee which has table department and employee respectively, the structure as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `department` (
  `dept_no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dept_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dept_no`)
)

CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `emp_no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dept_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`)
)
```

Can anyone throw a light on this? I had a hard time figuring out the reason, thanks

Kurt

Comment: What's the output? What does "not working at all" mean? You don't have a failing test case anywhere.

Comment: Hi, no error output but no data inserted either, I managed to fix the issue with atomikos finally